# ng-quill output. remove html tag but retain its value

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5.1

i've been using nq-quill richtext editor in my app, whenever i persist the data in the nq-quill editor and view it to the view page only the data and the corresponding html tag not the desired value like **bold**, **underlined**, **italic** etc. i am building it in php with laravel

any idea would be appreciated.. tnx

so far this the snippet. it only remove the tag element.

```
$question = Question::create();
    $question->question = ucwords(Html2Text::convert($request->question));
    $question->subject_slug = $request->subject_slug;
    $question->save();
```

Comment: it's really unclear your question, I cannot understand.

Comment: have you ever used ng-quill?

Comment: my question is how to remove the html tag but retain its value when u want to view that certain data into the view page using ng-quill text editor,..